# Angular - Hide a table row in ngFor if it meets condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular app that is rendering a table of employee details. There is a datapoint called `Optional` that determines if it should show up by default.

My goal here is to hide these rows by default and then be able to toggle them on/off with a click of a button.

Example:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" *ngIf="s.fields">
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let f of s.fields.field" [class.hidden]="f.Optional == 1">
        <td>{{ f.FieldTitle }}</td>
        <td>{{ f.Value }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So far, I have it hiding the rows correctly that are optional by adding a class to them.

I ultimately need to be able to click a button to show/hide these hidden rows but I am unsure how to go about this approach.

Do I use CSS for this or somehow create a 2-way binding or model for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution for you, using ng-container and a function to determine the state based on optional and toggle state.

**TS**

```
state: boolean = false;

isAllowed = (optional) => {
  return optional === 0 ? true : this.state;
}

changeState = () => {
  this.state = !this.state;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" *ngIf="s.fields">
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let f of s.fields.field">
        <ng-container *ngIf="isAllowed(f.Optional)">
          <td>{{ f.FieldTitle }}</td>
          <td>{{ f.Value }}</td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button (click)="changeState()">Show/Hide</button>
```

Comment: This worked great! I didn't know about `ng-container`. HTML tables are very strict so I wasn't able to do things like wrap a `tr` in a `div` to use logic on it, but this essentially allows that parent level that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data look something like that:

```
  s = {
    fields: {
      field: [
        {
          FieldTitle: 'field 1',
          Value: ' value 1',
          Optional: '1'
        },
        {
          FieldTitle: 'field 2',
          Value: ' value 2',
          Optional: '0'
        },
        {
          FieldTitle: 'field 3',
          Value: ' value 3',
          Optional: '1'
        },
        {
          FieldTitle: 'field 4',
          Value: ' value 4',
          Optional: '0'
        },
                {
          FieldTitle: 'field 5',
          Value: ' value 5',
          Optional: '0'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This can be achieved with simple conditions on table data and a simple `click` listener:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" *ngIf="!isToggled && s.fields">
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let f of s.fields.field">
        <td *ngIf="f.Optional == 1">{{ f.FieldTitle }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="f.Optional == 1">{{ f.Value }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button (click)="onToggle()">toggle</button>
```

Make sure you have on your **component.ts** the `isToggled` boolean set to `false` and an `onToggle` function.

Sample: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2n5wpv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This is very close. You are correct about my structure of data as well. The end goal here is that the `optional = 0` always show up and when its `optional = 1` it is hidden until the button is clicked. In your example, 2, 4, 5  should shown by default and the toggle should show/hide 1,3.